# How to declare array member into class in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to add TMistakes2D to class TForm1, something in the way?

```
type
  TMistakes2D: array of TStringList;
  end;
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    mistakes2D: TMistakes2D;
  end;
```

This prints error...

> Field Form1.mistakes2D does not have a corresponding component. Remove the declaration?

Comment: That's not *passing an arry*. That's declaring a member (field) variable.

Comment: You just needed to press F1 on the error message. Then the [help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Field_field_name_does_not_have_a_corresponding_component._Remove_the_declaration) would pop *"The first section of your form's class declaration is reserved for use by the Form Designer."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first section after the declaration of a form (TForm) is reserved for the IDE's use when dragging and dropping components. It's automatically assumed to be `published`, as it's used by the VCL's streaming system when a form is being created from the DFM file at runtime. The automatic `published` visibility forces RTTI information to be generated for items in that section so they can be properly identified and created during that streaming process.

You can see how this works by creating a new blank form and then looking at the source, which will look something like this:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Dropping a button on the form will add the declaration of that button at the top, just below the form declaration:

```
type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

To declare a field (member) variable of the class, include it in the `private`, `protected`, or `public` section of the class.

```
type 
  TMistakes2D: array of TStringList;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private              // Can also be public or protected
    mistakes2D: TMistakes2D;
  end;
```

Answer (score 3):

A class declaration is divided into sections, delimited by `private`, `protected` and `public`.

The form editor in Delphi reserves the first section for its own use.  That's where it puts the declarations of all the components and events that you create from the editor.  If you try to add anything to that section manually, it might get confused.  In this case, it's saying that according to the PAS file there should be a component named Mistakes2D, but the DFM file has no such component.

To add your own fields and methods, you need to begin another section by adding another private, protected or public.

```
type
  tMyForm = class(TForm)
    // this area is reserved for the Delphi form editor

  private // This could be 'public' or 'protected'
    // your code can go here

  end;
```